# Партицирование POstgresql по схеме

Tags: postgresql

День добрый! Не получилось найти в интернете ответ на вопрос: возможно ли осуществлять партицирование всех таблиц определенной схемы (или схем) на другой узел. Буду благодарен за любой "пинок" в нужную сторону.

Comment: Я приношу глубочайшие извинения уважаемые телепаты, я забыл снять фольгированную кепочку! Я перепутал понятия) Не партицировать по схеме а шардить... Шардинг всех таблиц определенной схемы, возможно ли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде разобрался сам. Как я понял готовых решения для такой задачи нет, но это все достаточно просто реализуется самостоятельно. Все очень просто 
`pg_dump -n <shema_name>`
ну и загрузить все это дело на другой машине. Минус то что в это время работать будет нельзя) Наверное идеальным решением было бы что то вроде временного включения репликации нужной схемы на нужный сервер, а потом ее удаление...